# RowRepeater in SAPUI5

Tags: json, sapui5

I have RowRepeater in my SAPUI5 application and I am using MatrixLayout to show data from JSON model in the view. All the data goes in one column. Is it possible to show data in two or more columns, instead of one?

Forexample, I have JSON model with 10 objects and I want to bind first five objects in one column an than another five in other column near the first column? How can I do this and which layout should I use?

Thanks!

Comment: easy: correct our json![ {}*5 ], [ {}*5 ] and aggregate with /0 and /1 :-)

Comment: I can't correct my JSON, because its generated from data base. I take data from database an depict it as JSON data.

Comment: Sure you can ;-) just take the generated JSON, and then restructure it (could be in a new JSON model if you want)

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind your field to part of your json model, and then display your field in part of the column.

An example in your case would be:

```
var text1 = new sap.m.Text({
text: {
        path: "modelName>/pathName"
      }
});

var text2 = new sap.m.Text({
text: {
        path: "modelName>/pathName2"
      }
});

var oMatrix = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({
      columns: 2,
      widths: ["50%", "50%"],
    });

oMatrix.createRow(text1, text2);
```